I accidentally deleted the wrong drive when installing Windows 11. How to recover the loss data?
As the title says, I deleted the wrong drive while installing Windows 11.
I have 2 drives on my laptop, one (SSD) for the OS and the other (HDD) for storing data. As I want to fresh install my Windows 11, in the installer I chose the option "Custom: Install Windows only (advanced)" and deleted the old Windows partitions. I was supposed to only delete the partitions on my SSD drive, but somehow I managed to deleted the HDD drive as well.
After installing Windows (on the SSD drive), I log in and open DiskManagement. Seeing that the HDD disk is greyed out with text "Unallocated", I right-clicked and choose (New Simple Volume) and clicked on 'next' until 'finish' (which I obviously shouldn't have done, I was an idiot).
I think by doing that I even formatted the disk. I don't want to touch diskmanagement again to verify if I did, I'm afraid I might mess something up again. Do you know if I can recover the loss data? I read somewhere that I can use Testdisk to recover delete partitions, but in my case I think since I have formatted it, it won't work.


If it appeared as "unallocated" before and was supposed to contain a partition, the problem happened before you formatted / tried to install something. Data recovery in such circumstances is always an hit and miss. You may try the usual tools but doin't keep your hopes high especially because the drive itself may be defective.

You don’t; You deleted the partitions, created new partitions, and then overwrote your data. Recovery of your original data is not possible

Have you ever made a drive image? Realistically, that would be your best chance. If the data is valuable, look to commercial data recovery -- but get an estimate on cost and on chance of success.

Hello, thank you for your response, I just edited my post. I just deleted the drive during windows installation and chose the option "New Simple Volumn" from the Disk Management app (which I supposed formatted the drive, but I'm not sure). From that point I never touched the drive, so I hope I didn't overwrite anything.

@QuốcAnhPhạmNguyễn - You absolutely did. Restore from your backups
